# How to properly calculate amount of Gunicorn's workers in multi venv environment?

Tags: gunicorn, worker

The official Gunicorn docs states:

> Generally we recommend (2 x $num_cores) + 1 as the number of workers to start off with

However what's the proper way of calculating number of workers if I'm running 10 small websites (5000 uv/day) on a dedicated server with 4c/8t CPU? The stack is: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisor.

For a single website it's obvious where to start 2x4 + 1 = 9, but what about my situation? How should I scale workers to not waste server resources?